# How to store the position of enemies on stage for a game in HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I`m trying to make a game like Doodle Jump and I need to generate the lines, where the character can jump on, but I have no idea how to do it, or how to store the position of each line on what the character can jump on. And there should be something to limit the number of lines as the game advances to make it more and more difficult, but without have impossible situations.

My main question is what would be a good method to store the position of each line ?
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial over here which shows you how to build a doodle jump style game using HTML5 Canvas http://michalbe.blogspot.com/2010/09/simple-game-with-html5-canvas-part-1.html.

In that example the developer creates an array of platform objects and draws them to canvas and then does some simple collision detection:

http://michalbe.blogspot.com/2010/09/tutorial-simple-game-with-html5-canvas_19.html

```
var GameLoop = function(){
clear();
//MoveCircles(5);
DrawCircles();

if (player.isJumping) player.checkJump();
if (player.isFalling) player.checkFall();

platforms.forEach(function(platform){
platform.draw();
});

checkCollision();

player.draw();
gLoop = setTimeout(GameLoop, 1000 / 50);
}
```